# Gradle build started failing with error - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, build

We are using gradle builds for our project. All of the sudden builds started failing with below error. I am new to gradle.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'.

> Could not resolve org.apache.poi:poi-excelant:3.15.
> > Could not get resource 'http://artifacthub.local/poi-excelant/3.15/ivy.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'http://artifacthub.local/poi-excelant/3.15/ivy.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: notresolvable
> Could not resolve commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8.
> Required by:
> project :
> Skipped due to earlier error

below is our gradle file.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
     maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.7.5"
    //classpath files('libs/our-custom.jar')  // (2)
    classpath "cz.malohlava:visteg:1.0.3"

  }
}

repositories
{
    maven {
            url "http://artifacthub.com/fmw-virtual/"
            credentials {
            }
            
    }
    
    ivy {
        url "http://artifacthub.com/epmpbcs-release-local/"
        layout 'pattern' , {
        m2compatible = false
            artifact "[organisation]/[artifact].[ext]"
            ivy '[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml'
        }
        credentials {
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'  // (3)
    compile(group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-lgpl', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-lgpl', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-xc', version: '1.9.11')
    compile(group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.0')
    compile(group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.16')  
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-excelant', version: '3.15'
    compile(group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '1.8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jar commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8 exists in http://artifacthub.local repo. If not include maven central repo in your build.gradle.

Comment: It is existing in repo